# change the Shape of drop down menu in bootstrap navbar

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I want to style the drop down menu  of bootstrap navbar as in the following image , but the  upper anchor ( i have put a blue circle around it in the uploaded picture) not appears . What i should add to my css  to draw it ?

Please help me
[image]

**my Css**

```
li.dropdown:hover > .dropdown-menu {
display: block;
}
.dropdown {
position:relative;
}

.dropdown>.dropdown-menu {
 -webkit-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
 -moz-border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius:0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-color:red;

        }

.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
            display:block;
        }
```

Comment: Create a snippet or fiddle to make it easier to show you how to do this.

Comment: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Vm7d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this effect you can add a small square then position it absolutely where you want it and then rotate it by 45 degrees. Then add a border to the top and left of the square:

CSS

```
.square {
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    left: 10px;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
    background-color: #fff;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Add the square div to your html:

HTML

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <div class="square"></div>
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
</ul>
```

To add this to other dropdown menus on the page just add another div inside with a class of .square

See it in action here: [fiddle](https://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/klRDW)